# I have a failing API call. What tools can I use to investigate it?

Tags: api, logging

Yesterday my app made 23 calls to salesforce's API that failed, and I would like to find a record of those calls on salesforce user account.

After about an hour of looking, I haven't been able to find any kind of api logs. The closest thing I found was `setup > monitoring > debug`, but that's completely empty and contains no information.

Where are these calls logged? I know it must be somewhere, I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Monitored Users" section of the "Debug Logs" page there is a "New" button that lets you nominate a user that logs will be recorded for (but only for the next 20 requests so repeat the setting as needed). So add the user that your requests are made through there to turn on the recording of the logs.

There is also a "Filters" link presented once you have created a monitored user that lets you vary the detail level of the logged information.